# conflict in mouseover and mouseout in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, onmouseover

I open/close the popup on mouse over/out  on hovering an element using its class name. I want that mouse over/out function to be happen on element that have similar class. When moving from one element to another at certain time popup is not get closed/open.

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.trend-cntnr',function(){
  var thisElem = $(this);
  clearTimeout(PopupDelay);
  PopupDelay=setTimeout(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        hide_popup();
        },500)
        thisElem.popover('show');
      },1000);
}).on('mouseout','.trend-cntnr',function(){
  var thisElem = $(this);
  thisElem.popover('hide');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="trend-cntnr">xxx</div>
    <div class="trend-cntnr">xxx</div>
    <div class="trend-cntnr">xxx</div>
    <div class="trend-cntnr">xxx</div>
    <div class="trend-cntnr">xxx</div>
    <div class="trend-cntnr">xxx</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This isn't really enough code to diagnose the problem (although the nested timeouts are rather odd). Could you please add the code of `hide_popup()` as well as the HTML and CSS too - preferably in an executable snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the response I updated my code. I am using bootstrap popover.